# Android preferences - Can they be hierarchical?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I can read and write shared preferences and have verified that the resulting XML file looks correct. But is it possible to build a hierarchy of preferences instead of just a flat list?

I'm accessing the preferences directly from my code, so the solution must not assume a preferences screen is present in the app. I have found the PreferenceGroup, PreferenceCategory, and PreferenceManager classes, but they seem to assume a preferences screen is present.

Comment: Define what you mean by "hierarchical", if you're not talking about PreferenceScreen. You can declare any number of preferences to be dependent on a given preference (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency).

Comment: @Hydrangea: By hierarchical I mean a structure where an item can have sub-items. The preferences are stored using SharedPreferences.Editor, and they reside in an XML file. Since hierarchical structures are possible in XML, I was hoping to find a way to build a structure representation of my preference data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible to build a hierarchy of preferences instead of just a flat list?

No, sorry. From the rest of your question, it's unclear why you are using `SharedPreferences` in the first place, instead of another persistent data model (database, XML file, JSON file, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite possible that I'm trying the wrong approach. Basically I'm porting a Windows application that stores settings in the Windows registry. The application accesses the persistent storage (registry or anything else) via an abstract interface, so all I need to do (in the scope of this question) is derive a new class that implements something like the registry for Android. E.g. deleting a key means deleting all sub-keys. Since the shared properties reside in an XML file, that seemed a promising approach - I just can't find the API for anything more than a flat list.

Comment: So maybe a separate XML file of my own is a better approach, since Java seems to offer pretty good facilities for reading/writing XML. Thanks and +1 :-)

Comment: @Dabbler: In general, `SharedPreferences` is a fine replacement for the registry, but only for a flat list of key-value pairs. If you make complex use of the registry, though, you are better served using some other data store.